# CS1513 error } expected

Tags: c#

I keep getting a CS1513 error on the following code in visual studios writing in C#

```
{
    class NotChineseZodiac
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            String YearBorn;
            int YearBornInt;
            Console.WriteLine("What was the year of your birth?");
            YearBorn = Console.ReadLine();
            YearBornInt = Convert.ToInt32(YearBorn);


            Console.WriteLine("You are" + (DateTime.Now.Year - YearBornInt));

            if ((DateTime.Now.Year - YearBornInt) < 18);
            Console.WriteLine("You Shall Not PASS");

            else
              Console.WriteLine("Please Proceed");

            Console.ReadLine(); // last enter key
```

Does anyone see my error??

Comment: space is not allowed between if else.

Comment: yes..remove the end semicolon here `if ((DateTime.Now.Year - YearBornInt) < 18);`

Comment: @m.kudi You can have blank lines or commented lines between an `if` and `else`, but you cannot have more than one code block between them, which is the case here.

Answer (score 5):

you have terminated this line with a semicolon:

```
if ((DateTime.Now.Year - YearBornInt) < 18);
```

correctly it would be:

```
if ((DateTime.Now.Year - YearBornInt) < 18)
        Console.WriteLine("You Shall Not PASS");
else
        Console.WriteLine("Please Proceed");
```

or for better  readability

```
if ((DateTime.Now.Year - YearBornInt) < 18)
{
     Console.WriteLine("You Shall Not PASS");
}
else
{
     Console.WriteLine("Please Proceed");
}
```

Comment: I disagree that adding curly brackets for the if and else statements adds readability for a single line statement.

Comment: You are welcome to disagree. For me it marks clearly what belongs to the if/else and avoids unnecessary errors. Its up to you or your company to handle it differently.